Replace dots/commas in string so that it can be cast to float
I'm trying to convert a str column from str to float (it's intended to be a float). However, the string have commas and dots and I'm not being able to correctly replace the values:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"numbers": ["1.004,00", "2.005,00", "3.006,00"]})
df = df.with_column(
    df["numbers"].str.replace(".", "").str.replace(",", ".").cast(pl.Float64)
)
print(df)

I'm getting:

ComputeError: conversion from str to f64 failed in column 'numbers'
for 3 out of 3 values: [".004.00", ".005.00", ".006.00"]

I Also tried just removing the "." with nothing using:
df = df.with_columns(df["numbers"].str.replace(".", ""))
print(df)

But I'm getting the values without the first number.

see this answer for why you should use pl.col syntax instead of using square bracket notation.

can't cast just take a locale to know what the decimal separator is?

This may help to change the decimals and thousands separators: https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_decimal_separator.html

str.replace uses regular expressions, so the dot matches the first character.  Just escape it:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({ "numbers": ["1.004,00", "2.005,00", "3.006,00"] })
df = (
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('numbers').str.replace("\.", "").str.replace(",", ".").cast(pl.Float64)
    )
)

print(df)

Output:
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ numbers │
│ ---     │
│ f64     │
╞═════════╡
│ 1004.0  │
│ 2005.0  │
│ 3006.0  │
└─────────┘

